# execute a function in a given time interval in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, c#-3.0

Good afternoon fellow Samaritans, I need to update a collectionview every 3 seconds, but I have not yet found a way to do it, I am implementing the MVVM pattern, but I have not seen anything clear about it, could you help me? greetings.

Comment: .NET has a variety of times in available in `System.Timers`